# Solving an optimization problem with Lagrange multipliers.

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

For $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$ with $a>0,b>0,c>0$ fixed and $\xi_{1},\xi_{2},\ldots,\xi_{N},\mu \in\mathbb{R}$ also fixed, I need to solve the following optimization problem:

$$
\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
{\displaystyle \inf_{\beta\in\mathbb{R},\:s\in\mathbb{R}^{N},\: r\in\mathbb{R}^{N}}} & {a+\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}s_{i} } & \\
\mbox{subject to} & {\displaystyle b\beta^{2}+ c(\mu-\xi_{i})(\beta+\mu-\xi_{i})+r_{i}= s_{i}   } & \forall i\leq N \\
& r_{i} \geq 0 & \forall i\leq N
\end{array}\right.
\tag{$\bigstar$}$$

**Remark:** I do not want to use solvers, my idea is to use Lagrange multipliers to determine exactly the optimal value.

**My attempt:**  Note that ($\bigstar$) is a problem with Equality and Inequality Constraints, so everything in this [link](http://mat.gsia.cmu.edu/classes/QUANT/NOTES/chap4/node6.html) works for ($\bigstar$) (That's what I think). Therefore, following the steps outlined in that link we have that the Lagrangian is:

$$\mathcal{L}(\beta,s,r,\lambda,\alpha)=a+\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}s_{i}+\sum_{i=1}^{N}\lambda_{i}(s_{i}-b\beta^{2}- c(\mu-\xi_{i})(\beta+\mu-\xi_{i})-r_{i})+\sum_{i=1}^{N}\alpha_{i}r_{i}.$$

According to the link to solve ($\bigstar$) I must solve the following system:
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{rclr}
\sum_{i=1}^{N}\lambda_{i}\left(-2b\beta-c(\mu-\xi_{i}) \right) &=& 0 \\
\frac{1}{N}+\lambda_{i}&=&0 & \forall i\leq N \\
-\lambda_{i}+\alpha_{i}&=&0 & \forall i\leq N\\
\alpha_{i}r_{i} &=&0 & \forall i\leq N\\
\alpha_{i}&\geq& 0 & \forall i\leq N\\
b\beta^{2}+ c(\mu-\xi_{i})(\beta+\mu-\xi_{i})+r_{i}-s_{i} &=&0 & \forall i\leq N\\
r_{i}&\geq& 0 & \forall i\leq N\\
\end{array}\right.
$$

But this system has problems, the second and third equations are contradictory with $\alpha_{i}\geq 0$. **I do not know what I am doing wrong, I would appreciate your help.**

Comment: Looks like you can get rid of $a$ by sending it to $0$ (it only appears in the objective function).  If $\alpha_i$ is your nonnegative Lagrange multiplier for the constraint $r_i\geq 0$ then it should be $-\sum_{i=1}^N \alpha_i r_i$ in your Lagrangian function, not $+\sum_{i=1}^N\alpha_ir_i$. This is equivalent to using constraints $-r_i \leq 0$.

Comment: If you just directly substitute your expression for $s_i$ into the objective function, it is easy to see (without Lagrange multiplier methods) that minimizing the objective occurs when $a=0$ and $r_i=0$ for all $i$. That is because the $a, r_1, ..., r_n$ variables appear separably in the objective function. So this problem reduces to minimizing a quadratic function of $\beta$.  There is no reason to use Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: @Michael I based on the link I mentioned in my post, in that document says that the constrains of the form $ h_{i}(x) \leq d_{i}$ pass in the Lagrangian to $ \sum_{i = 1}^{N}\alpha_{i}(d_{i}-h_{i}(x) ) $, in the context of my problem $ h_{i}(\beta,s,r) = -r_{i} $ and $ d_ {i} = 0 $. **Does the document which I am basing this wrong?**
$$$$
On the other hand, $a$ is not a variable, it is a constant, for me it is important that it be greater than zero, **does your reasoning in the second comment change if $ a> 0 $?**

Comment: That link is talking about _maximizing_ a function, but you are _minimizing_.  So there is a sign change. But, again, you don't need Lagrange multipliers to see $r_i=0$ for all $i$. But you can also see that from the (corrected) Lagrange multiplier equations, $1/N + 1/\lambda_i = 0$, $-\lambda_i - \alpha_i=0$, $\alpha_i r_i=0$.